# set the nameserver of my hosting on the settings of my domain

Tags: domains, dns, nameserver

I have a problem with the setup of my domain, to be able to use it with the nameservers of my host.
immediately after confirming the settings the site of my domain (register.it), warned me to wait 24 / 48h for the propagation of the domain, but for some reason, after this time, the migration of the domain on my hosting has been canceled .
the support advised me to perform a test to check for any problems, the feedback was this:

https://pastebin.com/a9jtGb3u

I also performed tests on zonemaster and the result was this:

https://www.zonemaster.net/export?type=HTML&lang=it&test_id=a1d5c19af7283767

could someone help me understand the results? what were the problems? Do you have any advice on how to solve?
thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have tested resolution of `otakugamers.it` on authoritative nameservers `ns1.server467.co.uk` and `ns2.server467.co.uk`

What the error report tails you is that these 2 nameservers are not configured correctly for your domain. So you need to contact the company handling these nameservers and make sure it configures them appropriately for your domain.

For example, they reply 'REFUSED' for NS records query, which is wrong:

```
$ dig @ns1.server467.co.uk otakugamers.it NS

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> @ns1.server467.co.uk otakugamers.it NS
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Sending:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50818
;; flags: rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 83ac17ec3aef1257
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;otakugamers.it.        IN NS

;; QUERY SIZE: 55

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 50818
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;otakugamers.it.        IN NS

;; Query time: 152 msec
;; SERVER: 62.210.247.90#53(62.210.247.90)
;; WHEN: Wed May 09 16:58:09 EST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43
```

On the registry authoritative nameservers, your domain name is still handled by `ns1.register.it` and `ns2.register.it`

```
$ dig @r.dns.it otakugamers.it NS

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> @r.dns.it otakugamers.it NS
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Sending:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38407
;; flags: rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 241c5877a0618c9e
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;otakugamers.it.        IN NS

;; QUERY SIZE: 55

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 38407
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;otakugamers.it.        IN NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
otakugamers.it.     10800 IN NS ns1.register.it.
otakugamers.it.     10800 IN NS ns2.register.it.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.register.it.    10800 IN A 195.110.124.140
ns2.register.it.    10800 IN A 195.7.227.1

;; Query time: 183 msec
;; SERVER: 193.206.141.46#53(193.206.141.46)
;; WHEN: Wed May 09 16:59:23 EST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 120
```

Comment: You now have changed your authoritative nameservers to `ns100.ovh.net` and  `dns100.ovh.net` and these two are in fact correctly configured for your domain name.